# Converting Method to Butcher tableau

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods, quadrature

Suppose that a method is given by $$y_{n+2/3} = y_n + h((1/3) f(y_{n+2/3}) + (1/3) f(y_{n}))$$ and $$y_{n+1} = y_n + h((3/4) f(y_{n+2/3}) + (1/4) f(y_{n})).$$ I am trying to obtain the Butcher tableau for this method. The main issue that I am having is how to deal with the $y_{n+2/3}$.

Are there any general guidelines for how to approach this? I considered using the substitution $y_{n+2/3} \approx (1/3) y_{n} + (2/3) y_{n+1}$, but this only seemed to make the problem more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
k_1=f(y_n), ~~~ k_2=f(y_{n+2/3})
$$
and rewrite your equations as
$$
y_{n+2/3}=y_n+\frac{h}3(k_1+k_2)\implies k_2=f\left(y_n+\frac{h}3(k_1+k_2)\right)
$$
to eliminate $y_{n+2/3}$ completely. This should now look familiar enough.

Comment: Thanks! We also write $y_n = y_n + h(0k_1 + 0k_2)$, right?. If so, this would imply that the table would be $$\begin{matrix}
    0 & | & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{2}{3} & | & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
     & | & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4}
\end{matrix}.$$

Comment: Yes. Usually, the zeros on the right, in the matrix part, are not printed. At least not those towards th upper-right corner.

Comment: Thanks. I will upvote the answer as soon I get 15 reputation.